# Using custom shell commands from python file

Tags: python, shell, command

I am going to try my best to explain the problem I am facing.
I created this custom shell command in linux

```
#!/bin/bash

function create() {
    python3 .create.py $1
    cd /home/simon/Linux_Storage/Projects/$FILEPATH$1
    code .
    echo "Project created."
    cd
}
```

What I am trying to do is to call it from a python script by using `os.system("create ")`, but i get this error: `sh: 1: create: not found` .
If I try to use any other default command like `os.system("date")`, or I just try to call my command from the terminal it works no problem.
Is there a way to access custom shell commands from a python file? Or should I abandon the idea?

Answer (score 2):

Prior to running your python program, you'll need to source the file containing the `create` script (lets call this create.sh).  You'll also need to export the function so that it will be available to any process you spawn.  For example:

```
. create.sh
export -f create
python -c 'import os; os.system("create")'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried providing the full path to the command?

It looks like you only provided the name for the command. Your shell may know where to find it, but you might need to specify it for Python.

Comment: @SimoneLiberti I mean the path to the file that contains the bash code

Comment: I actually stored the command inside a file (my_commands.sh). How can I access it?

Comment: @SimoneLiberti As per https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-system-method/   , the system function just runs whatever string you type into it. So you could type the full path, somthing like os.system("/path/to/file/my_commands.sh)"

Comment: I tried with `os.system("/home/simon/.my_commands.sh")` and `os.system("/home/simon/.my_commands.sh create ")` but now it just does nothing at all

Comment: @SimoneLiberti you might consider making the file a script and removing the function.

Comment: @SimoneLiberti Also make the file has permission to be executed: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/run-execute-sh-shell-script/

Comment: @SimoneLiberti from that site: How to use chmod command to run .sh shell script in Linux

Another recommend option is to set an executable permission using the chmod command as follows:
chmod +x file.sh

Now your can run your .sh file as follows
./file.sh
/path/to/file.sh

Comment: @SimoneLiberti Also don't forget that if you start the path with / then you are starting from the root directory, if you start it with ~ you will start it from the HOME directory, and if you start it with . it will start in the CURRENT directory (whichever directory your python app is in)

Comment: @SimoneLiberti Again try taking out the function "create" and just write the script by itself and then run it.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the full path as @majneeds2chill mentioned, provided the function is called inside the bash script. You can also add the full path to an alias called "create" to make the custom command feeling.